# Cálculo de reajuste de salário (de acordo com categoria) com if else só retorna a primeira condição de 4. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if, else

Criei um código JavaScript com if else para mostrar na tela o reajuste de um salário de acordo com a categoria do trabalhador selecionada num input type ="radio". Ocorre que apenas a primeira condição é calculada, independente da escolha de categoria pelo usuário. De antemão, muito grato pela ajuda!

```
function calcular() {
                var ca = document.getElementById("categoriaA");
                var cb = document.getElementById("categoriaB");
                var ck = document.getElementById("categoriaK");
                var cl = document.getElementById("categoriaL");                
                var x = Number(salario.value);
                
                var novoSalario; 
                var result = document.getElementById ("res");
                result.value = novoSalario;

                if(ca=true){
                    novoSalario = x + 100;
                    result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;                                      
                }else if(cb=true){
                    novoSalario = x + 150;
                    result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;                    
                }else if(ck=true){
                    novoSalario = x + 200;
                    result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;
                }else if(cl=true){
                    novoSalario = x + 250;
                    result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;
                }else{
                    result.innerHTML = `Você precisa marcar a sua categoria`;
                }                
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! Aqui vai o código corrigido:

""
function calcular() {

```
            var category = document.getElementsByName("categoria")               
            var x = Number(salario.value);
            
            var novoSalario; 
            var result = document.getElementById ("res");
            result.value = novoSalario;

            if(category[0].checked){
                novoSalario = x + 100;
                result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;                                      
            }else if(category[1].checked){
                novoSalario = x + 150;
                result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;                    
            }else if(category[2].checked){
                novoSalario = x + 200;
                result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;
            }else if(category[3].checked){
                novoSalario = x + 250;
                result.innerHTML = `Você passa a ganhar R$ ${novoSalario}`;
            }else{
                result.innerHTML = `Você precisa marcar a sua categoria`;
            }                
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

""